# How to use a list of a list of Objects in java?

Tags: java, collections

In the below mentioned program array is a List passed as an argument to this function. The task is to cut the array into lists of LookupTable of defined size and then add them into binlists. In this case what should be the declaration of binlists? Should it be List ? Because either way it gives me an error at the add() function. It works totally fine if I use all the Lists mentioned as raw type. But my intention is to make it parametric.

```
    protected List<LookupTable> binlists;
    binlists = new ArrayList<LookupTable>(nofbins);

    while(chunk+binsize <= tot_size)
    {
        List tempsort = (List<LookupTable>)arry.subList(chunk,chunk+binsize);
        System.out.println(tempsort.size());
        binlists.add(tempsort);
        chunk = chunk+binsize;
    }
```

Comment: your tempsort should use generics as List<LookupTable> tempsort.

Comment: In fact, why is arry not generic on the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `addAll` method to add a list to an existing list: -

```
binlists.addAll(tempsort);
```

And you should always declare your `List` to be of `generic type`.

So, declare your `tempSort` list as a `generic list` of type `LookUpTable`: -

```
List<LookupTable> tempsort = 
                  (List<LookupTable>)arry.subList(chunk,chunk+binsize);
```

In fact, you can save yourself from that `typecast` if you declare your `arry` list too as generic type.

Comment: Why would one need addAll(...). Wouldn't using add() to add the tempsort object(s) to binlist suffice?

Comment: @Arham. Since he is adding an entire `tempSort` List to the existing list (binlists), so, addAll is needed.

Comment: but the generics defined as List<LookupTable> binlists asks for adding only an object of LookUpTable. And tempsort is exactly that. It doesn't matter what tempsort actually contains.

Comment: @Arham. No. `tempsort` is a `List<LookupTable>`

Comment: or rather binlists should be List<List<LookUpTable>>...just for the sake of add(...) operation!! :D

Comment: @Arham. That will make the iteration of `binlists` even more bulky later on. Will require Nested Loop. Since we have got the method `addAll`, we can easily use it.